# Removing features with high p-values lowers accuracy

Tags: p-value, feature-selection, accuracy, model-evaluation

I'm training my model with 20 features and getting an `accuracy` of `0.95`, however, If I check `p-values` with a `significance level=0.05`, I'm left with only 7 features which has brought down my accuracy to `0.90`.

Why is accuracy going down, isn't high `p-value` suppose to mean not so important feature? Also, I'm confused If I should check `p-values` or `Variance Inflation Factor` to chose my best features.

Comment: Related: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Comment: Additionally, No.  P-values do not at all (or, if you're feeling generous, only weakly) indicate whether a predictor is useful in a predictive model.  They simply measure a different thing (*if* the true parameter is zero, what is the probability we would observe a parameter estimate this extreme).  If variable selection is needed, there is technology available to do so, but p-values are not one of those technologies.